# How can I make it so the Tkinter button can only be pressed once?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code where I am trying to have it so I can only press the button once and then it becomes disabled, but I keep getting the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, I'm not so sure what I am doing incorrect. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

team_array = []
team_dict = {}

def score_event1_team():
    global team_array
    global team_dict

    #First Event, 1st Team, Adding 15 points.
    event1T = str(input("What team was first place?"))
    
    #ADDING 15 POINTS TO FIRST TEAM IN THE DICTIONARY WITH GET METHOD.
    team_dict[event1T] = team_dict.get(event1T, 0) + 15
    print(team_dict)
    print(f"Team {event1T} has been added 15 points.")

    if (button_event_1['state'] == NORMAL):
        button_event_1['state'] = DISABLED


root = Tk()
root.title("Sports Event Organiser!")
root.geometry("600x500")

button_event_1 = Button(root,
    text="Event Pending",
    bg="white",
    height = 1,
    command=(score_event1_team),
    state = NORMAL,
).pack(pady = 10)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your following code segment, where you are creating a button

```
button_event_1 = Button(root,
    text="Event Pending",
    bg="white",
    height = 1,
    command=(score_event1_team),
    state = NORMAL,
).pack(pady = 10)
```

You are calling `pack(pady = 10)` immediately on the button due to which your `button_event_1` object is not referring to the button but None returned by `pack()`

the solution is simple, remove it from there and then pack the button separately, after button initialization

```
button_event_1 = Button(root,
    text="Event Pending",
    bg="white",
    height = 1,
    command=(score_event1_team),
    state = NORMAL,
)

button_event_1.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are doing wrong is this line button_event_1 = Button(....).pack() as you are packing it with the button and pack returns a nontype object you need to do button_event_1 = Button(....) and than button_event_1.pack() both in separate lines. The pack function returns a none type object and in your question thus button_event_1 is None